# Reading Properties file in Maven Java Project created by maven-archetype-quickstart

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to read a properties file using the below code on a Java Project created using Maven ArchetypeId=maven-archetype-quickstart

```
(properties = new Properties()).load(DbCopy.class.getClassLoader()
   .getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

And it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:284)
  at benz.bnp.db.DbCopy.main(DbCopy.java:77)
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Where is your "config.properties" exactly located? And how do you run your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the target folder, if it contains your properties file. Hopefully it will not contain. To include your property file edit your pom:

```
<build>        
<resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
     </resources>
</build>
```

Add it to your POM.xml and configure the same for your properties file.

Comment: I tried you solution and when I look in "included" list in Eclipse; it sets to all. In fact, it should have been **/*.java and **/*.properties.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

1. Right Click on Project in Eclipse
2. Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path
3. In Source tab : Add **/*.properties in "Included" for "src/main/java".

The problem was: maven-archetype-quickstart only sets **/*.java in the "Included" list.

Comment: It will work but not a good solution and would not work in different remote environment (dev, staging, production) as you might need different properties configuration for different environments. And using this way your jar/war file will be generated along with properties.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `config.properties` is under `src/main/resources` try something like this :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try(InputStream resourceStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
    props.load(resourceStream);
}
```

Comment: It still wont solve the purpose as sometimes properties files might be in different packages. and this code will try to look in root folder.