# Maven Properties file not found

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven web application.
The following is my project structure where I have placed my properties file.
[image]

The following is my code which I am using to read this file:

```
public static Properties loadProducerProperty() throws FileException {
     Properties myProperties = new Properties();

     try {
         String resourceName = "newproperties.properties"; // could also be a constant
         ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
         try (InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
             myProperties.load(resourceStream);
         }


     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         throw new FileException();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new FileException();
     }

     return myProperties;
 }
```

But I am getting `FileNotFound` Exception

I have gone through the following link and tried other things also but I am getting the same error :

[Cannot load properties file from resources directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348657/cannot-load-properties-file-from-resources-directory)

What I am doing wrong here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a slash in front of the filename:

```
String resourceName = "/newproperties.properties"; // could also be a constant
```