# Cannot read properties from java build path

Tags: java, buildpath

I'm working on a simple JSE project with maven configuration (Although I think it has nothing to do with Running the project from Eclipse). And when I try to get a Properties file with a FileInputStream I get FileNotFoundException.

Here's the source configuration
[image]

And here's the project structure :

[image]

This is part of the code I'm using to read properties file :

```
    prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(new File(FLUX_PROPERTIES+".properties"));
        prop.load(input);

        paramDir = prop.getProperty(PARAM_DIR);
        input.close();
        prop = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.error("Cannot find properties file");
    }
```

Any hint please?

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348657/cannot-load-properties-file-from-resources-directory

Comment: I used the solution on the link and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @sasikumar what if I want to write on the file? I can't use getResourceAsStream to write, do you know how to fix that?