# Unable to find property file Java and TestNG

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Already tried this solution but no luck yet :

> [Cannot load properties file from resources directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348657/cannot-load-properties-file-from-resources-directory)

**My Code:**

```
protected WebDriver driver;
public static Properties prop;    

@BeforeSuite
    public void setup()
    {

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        //Calling property file function here
        ReadData();

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));

    }

    public void ReadData()
        {  prop = new Properties();
            try {
                prop.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\projectname\\src\\main\\resources\\DataFile.properties"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
```

Getting Exception :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

File is already there and I have tried lot of diff. file path like full path, path starts from `src` ect.

**Project Structure :**

> http://prntscr.com/g1bpq2

**UPATE :**

1. It works when I removed `.properties` extension from filepath.
2. Still I am not sure that why intellij did not add file extension as .properties. Because I am sure that I have created file with type `properties`.

Comment: Are you using `Maven`?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Yes.

Comment: @HelpingHands paste a screenshot of the folder structure where the property file exists.

Comment: @HelpingHands The correct path to properties file as per screenshot of project structure is 'D:\Facebook_Login\src\main\resources\DataFile.properties'
The project folder name is 'D:\Facebook_Login' and not 'D:\Demo_Login'

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui - That is just for example here. So that's not an issue.

Comment: I can see files having '.xml' and '.iml' extensions. Can you confirm that the DataFile is a '.properties' file and not a '.txt'.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to read file?

Comment: Following @Zeeshan Siddiqui - is there any chance that the file extension is hidden in the directory you are viewing. Depending on settings, file extensions may not show. Coujkd be worth checking subdirectory settings to view extensions and hidden files.

Comment: ^  sensible question

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder - I am not sure why it is not displaying extension there but I  can created properties file based on this guild : [Guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-properties-files.html)

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder - It works now. Thanks.

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui - It works by removing .properties from file path. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear, good suggestion from @DebanjanB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Instead of :

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\projectname\\src\\main\\resources\\DataFile.properties"));
```

Can you try:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/DataFile.properties"));
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @HelpingHands Did this Question got Answered? Thanks

Comment: No buddy. Getting error : **java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\src\main\resources\DataFile.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)**

Comment: So its completely clear that you don't have a file by the name **DataFile`.properties`** at "D:\\projectname\\src\\main\\resources\\" sub-directory. Put a proper file there and check the Answer. Thanks

Comment: You are correct. I tried to access file without .properties and it works. But still I am not sure why intelliJ does not add extension .properties even I added file type properties.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you :) you may need to configure some intelliJ settings. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\\` in java to give the absolute path like below :-

```
D:\\Demo_Login\\src\\main\\resources\\DataFile.properties
```

You can use `File.separator` instead of putting `\\`

OR

you can do something like below :-

```
        File src=new File("src\\lib\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe");

        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",src.getAbsolutePath());
```

OR

You can try something like below using `.` which start directory from project root directory :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src"+File.separator+"lib"+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe")
```

OR

Start with `src` like that :-

```
"src/main/resources/DataFile.properties"
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @ShubhamJain Any reason for `/` to malfunction ?

Comment: @Helping Hands - I have added few approaches  .. please try them

Comment: Sure. Let me try.

Comment: @DebanJanB - Please see the answer in below link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091506/what-is-the-backslash-character

Comment: Thanks :) What you pointed is `What is the backslash character (\\)?` where as my question is `Any reason for "/" to malfunction`? Thanks

Comment: @ShubhamJain - Still getting **java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\DataFile.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)**

Comment: @HelpingHands - Can you please open up a command prompt or the terminal from IntelliJ and then run a `dir` (or) a `ls -l` command and share the output ? I think your file name is just `DataFile` but you are trying to read it as `DataFile.properties`. Reading a property file shouldn't be so complicated. There's obviously something that is missing here.

Comment: @DebanJanB - May it will help you - https://blogs.oracle.com/brewing-tests/clash-of-slashes-versus

Comment: @ShubhamJain - Thanks it works now when I removed .properties extension from path.