# Create config.properties in Java with IntelliJ

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, config

I tried to create a config.properties on my project, but I don't understand where I need to place my ReadFile class.
My config.properties file is situated under *resources* folder, while my ReadFile class is situated under *src*.

```
public class ReadPropertyFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

And the error is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/config.properties (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
at ReadPropertyFile.main(ReadPropertyFile.java:14)
```

Comment: Is it a maven project?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam no

Comment: Did you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder?

Comment: @soorapadman it uses the .csv extension

Comment: @xAspired mm How about this sir ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348657/cannot-load-properties-file-from-resources-directory#answer-33886409

Comment: If you place the file into the root of `resources` directory - you should be able to access it by just specifying the file name.